# Typo in Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 114 he wanted to prove that

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$$

In order to demonstrate this fact he find first the residues at the poles:

[image]

I didn't understand how this identity highlighted above can be true. My calculations give me $\frac{1}{4e^{\pi/4}}$ (which he found in the end).

So is this a typo in his book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z-a_1)(z-a_2)(z-a_3)(z-a_4)}$, $$(z-a_1)f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z-a_2)(z-a_3)(z-a_4)}.$$

But the right-hand side is well-defined and continuous at $z=a_1$, so we get that $$\lim_{z\to a_1}(z-a_1)f(z)=\frac{a_1^2}{(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)}.$$

Comment: Of course, thank you very much!